# How does make file execute the dynamic targets?

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I am trying to understand a makefile and the usage of dynamic target seems pretty confusing. I am not able to understand how these dynamic target is being invoked in the makefile.

I tried debugging the following by printing the shell commands(make V=1) but I could not clear my doubts. I see file/1, file/2, file/3 and file/4 being built but I don't see any loops or multiple calls to this target being made. I also tried looking into the https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html doc but didn't get any related information there as well. Any explanation about such dynamic target and their execution would be really helpful.

```
PROGS= \
    path/to/file/1 \
    path/to/file/2
EXTRA_PROGS= \
    path/to/file/3 \
    path/to/file/4 
GO_BIN_BUILD=$(SOME_COMMAND_TO_BUILD_GO_BINARY)
GO_BIN_BUILD_DEPS=$(SOME_COMMAND_TO_BUILD_GO_DEPENDENCIES)

CTF_INTEGRATION_TESTS=$(foreach root,$(CTF_DIRS),$(root)/$(notdir $(root)).suite)
$(PROGS) $(EXTRA_PROGS) $(CTF_INTEGRATION_TESTS): $(GO_BIN_BUILD_DEPS) #the dynamic target in question.
    $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _dynamic target_?  Do you mean targets created by implicit rules, such as pattern rules?  I don't see any pattern rules defined in your makefile.

Comment: @MadScientist, pardon me if I am making any mistake but isn't ```$(PROGS) $(EXTRA_PROGS) $(CTF_INTEGRATION_TESTS): $(GO_BIN_BUILD_DEPS)``` a dynamic target? A target that is constructed using the value of the variables. I am pretty new to make syntax, will delete the question if it contains the wrong info,

Comment: It's just that "dynamic target" isn't a term used in the make manual or POSIX spec so I didn't know what you meant by it.

Comment: Are you asking how the target is being invoked, or how the rule is building those files?

Comment: @Beta, I am trying to understand how these rules are invoked. I am under the impression that these targets are like functions in the program, they don't do anything until they are invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this rule means what you think it means:

```
$(PROGS) $(EXTRA_PROGS) $(CTF_INTEGRATION_TESTS): $(GO_BIN_BUILD_DEPS)
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
```

First, make will expand all the variables in the first line (the second line is a recipe so it is not expanded until make wants to build a target).

As a result of this you get something like this:

```
path/to/file/1 path/to/file/2 path/to/file/3 path/to/file/4 a/a.suite b/b.suite : dep1 dep2 dep3
```

where `a/a.suite` and `b/b.suite` are the results of `foreach` function (without knowing the value of the `CTF_DIRS` variable I can't say what the real values might be) and `dep1`, `dep2`, `dep3` are the results of running `SOME_COMMAND_TO_BUILD_GO_DEPENDENCIES` which I assume is some `$(shell ...)` command.

This is interpreted as if you declared individual rules for every one of these files with the same recipe, so like this:

```
path/to/file/1 : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
path/to/file/2 : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
path/to/file/3 : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
path/to/file/4 : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
a/a.suite : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
b/b.suite : dep1 dep2 dep3
        $(GO_BIN_BUILD)
```

Comment: thanks. And I assume all these expanded targets are invoked once their corresponding dependencies are present(built/processed). In this case, the dependencies would be some other go files so the targets will be built once those files present, is that correct?

Comment: Maybe or maybe not.  It's not the case that make always builds every target in the makefile.  Make chooses which target(s) to build first by the command line, so if you run `make a/a.suite` for example, it will build just that file.  If no target is requested on the command line, the the _first_ explicit target in the makefile will be built (and all its prerequisites).  If there are no other targets in your makefile before the above, then only `path/to/file/1` will be built (after its prerequisites are built) and nothing else.